# mysqli_fetch_assoc error

Tags: php, sql

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mutli_page_form');

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM wills_children WHERE id=77");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$data = unserialize($row['children']);
```

error

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

What seems to be the issue ?

The serialized data it's trying to pull;

```
a:1:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;s:15:\"Natural Chlid 1\";i:1;s:15:\"Natural Chlid 2\";i:2;s:15:\"Natural Chlid 3\";}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data = unserialize($row['children']);
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```